# Fabric js - Set Canvas width and height to 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, fabricjs

I am using the Fabric js 4.3.1 library and would like to be able to adapt the canvas area to its parent div #contCanvasLogo.

I've made a few attempts but nothing works, the canvas keeps resizing by itself.
This is my code but not working:

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.setHeight('100%');
canvas.setWidth('100%');
```

```css
#contCanvasLogo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
background: black;
}

#canvas{border:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.1/fabric.js" integrity="sha512-CzyxOXSECwo2nGJQZ2P8fdDxWVMVzn0jNdT2lYJ3afbqDJbaQ4qxgv9sLc85f6KP8HO2y929Bu+lnPKGC3ofSg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="contCanvasLogo">
  <canvas id="canvas" class="resize canvasLogo"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the height and width by retrieving the data from the parent container.

```
canvas.setHeight(document.getElementById("contCanvasLogo").clientHeight);
canvas.setWidth(document.getElementById("contCanvasLogo").clientWidth);
```

Comment: Man good idea and thanks for reply, but if my parent div#contCanvasLogo has width: 100% and height: 100% how can i do?

Comment: It's will work fine because the value from clientHeight/Width are translated in pixels